# JavaFx TextFields in text

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I'm loading text from an XML file. I want this text to have input fields in it, like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [pbrd.co](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HoYoYceQ.png))</sub>

I think it can be done by using WebView, but loading it with pain.
Or the hard way, by calculating a location of each input field.

Is there an easy way to do it without using WebView to not destroy my app desing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `TextFlow` with `Text` and `TextField` children for this purpose:

```
TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(
        new Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque "),
        createTextField(),
        new Text(" sit amet nibh ut ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque consequat tincidunt mattis. Phasellus "),
        createTextField(),
        new Text(" , tempor posuere orci et, posuere tempor ligula. Maecenas nisi justo, viverra a lacus et, eleifend porttitor"
                + " metus. Sed finibus nisi in ipsum facilisis fringilla. Curabitur porttitor tortor et eros pulvinar accumsan. "
                + "Quisque vestibulum turpis sed neque suscipit, et lacinia nibh tristique. Fusce a feugiat purus."));
textFlow.setPrefWidth(400);
```

Comment: Thanks!
I got it working, but I had to use the code like this, can you tell me why?
TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();

ObservableList list = textFlow.getChildren();
list.addAll(
    new Text("Lorem ipsum dolor s"),
    createTextField(),
    new Text(" sit amet nibh ut ornare. Phasellus "),
    createTextField(),
    new Text(" , tempor posuere orci et, posuere")
    );

textFlow.setPrefWidth(400);

Comment: No idea. The constructor should have the same effect as adding the children to the child list later...

Comment: I got it! I was returning Object from createTextField() method, instead of textField.